# WebPack 5 with dotenv - Unexpected character '@'

Tags: javascript, webpack, google-chrome-extension, dotenv, webpack-5

Despite there being a lot of questions similar to this, none of them have resolved the issue I'm facing when using Webpack with Dotenv.

I installed dotenv, and some environment variables have `@` chars. When I run `npx webpack`, these chars aren't being parsed correctly, resulting in an error.

**EDIT:** The error log below shows the error in `` console.log(`${@2022@89aou43i76h3rg5b2a9e235670fc0}`) ``, which could lead us to think the problem is a invalid variable name (starting with `@`). The thing is, in .env file, this is the VALUE (modified when I posted the question, of course), not the NAME of a password entry. The entry in .env is: `MY_SECRET="@2022@89aou43i76h3rg5b2a9e235670fc0"`.

In my worker-main.js file, that line is `` console.log(`${process.env.MY_SECRET}`) ``. Its like Dotenv preparsed the line, then Webpack is trying to parse again after this.

This is my webpack configuration:

```
const path = require("path")
const webpack = require('webpack')
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config({
    path: path.join(__dirname, '.env')
})

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        content: "./src/js/content-main.js",
        worker: "./src/js/worker-main.js"
    },
    mode: "production",
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js?$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules)/,
            include: path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
            use: {
            loader: "babel-loader"
            }
        },
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        "process.env": dotenv.parsed
        }),
    ],
}
```

These are my npm dependencies (yes, there are only a few):

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.13",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.2",
    "webpack": "^5.74.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0"
}
```

The error when I run `npx webpack`:

```
ERROR in ./src/js/worker-main.js + 8 modules
Unexpected character '@' (5:17)
|
| chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(tab => {
|   console.log(`${@2022@89a47df48e74b2a9e21500fc19b97710}`);
|   const details = {
|     tabId: tab.id
while analyzing module C:\misc\Projetos\sisifo-ruy-andrade\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js!C:\misc\Projetos\sisifo-ruy-andrade\src\js\worker-main.js for concatenation
SyntaxError: Unexpected character '@' (5:17)
|
| chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(tab => {
|   console.log(`${@2022@89a47df48e74b2a9e21500fc19b97710}`);
|   const details = {
|     tabId: tab.id
while analyzing module C:\misc\Projetos\sisifo-ruy-andrade\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js!C:\misc\Projetos\sisifo-ruy-andrade\src\js\worker-main.js for concatenation
    at Object.pp$4.raise (C:\misc\Projetos\sisifo-ruy-andrade\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:3459:15)    at Object.pp.getTokenFromCode (C:\misc\Projetos\sisifo-ruy-andrade\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:5121:10)
    at Object.pp.readToken (C:\misc\Projetos\sisifo-ruy-andrade\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:4808:17)
    at Object.readToken (C:\misc\Projetos\sisifo-ruy-andrade\node_modules\acorn-import-assertions\lib\index.js:55:24)
    at Object.pp.nextToken (C:\misc\Projetos\sisifo-ruy-andrade\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:4799:17)
    at Object.pp.next (C:\misc\Projetos\sisifo-ruy-andrade\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:4760:10)   
    at Object.pp$9.eat (C:\misc\Projetos\sisifo-ruy-andrade\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:690:12)   
    at Object.pp$9.expect (C:\misc\Projetos\sisifo-ruy-andrade\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:754:10)    at Object.pp$5.parseTemplate (C:\misc\Projetos\sisifo-ruy-andrade\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:3057:12)
    at Object.pp$5.parseExprAtom (C:\misc\Projetos\sisifo-ruy-andrade\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2833:19)
```

What can I do for webpack to parse it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with webpack, it's the javascript variable name issue.
the name of a variable in javascript can't start with `@`.

Look closely at the error log:

`console.log`(`${@2022@89a47df48e74b2a9e21500fc19b97710}`);

`@2022` is not a valid variable name.

Comment: In .env, this is the VALUE (modified when I posted the question, of course), not the NAME of a password entry. The entry in .env is: ```MY_SECRET="@2022@89a6oai76hf74b2a9e21500fc1910"```

Comment: In my worker-main.js file, that line is ```console.log(`${process.env.CLIENT_SECRET}`)```. Its like Dotenv preparsed, then Webpack is trying to parse again after this.

Comment: You need to embed the quotes in the value e.g. process.env.CLIENT_SECRET = JSON.stringify(MY_SECRET)

Comment: To retrieve a value from .env file I need to use ```Json.stringify(key)```? I've used Dotenv in PHP, and it's much simpler than this.

Comment: what happens if you add `output: {environment: {templateLiteral: false}},` to your `webpack.config.js`?

Comment: Placed it in the same level of the ```entry```, but returns the same error.

Comment: Sorry to hear that last try: what happens if you remove `"process.env"` from the `plugins`?

Comment: It packs, but Dotenv doesn't work (as expected).